# Jquery post com problemas para acessar uma classe php

Tags: php, jquery, namespace

Estou com problemas para acessar uma classe via $.post do jquery.
Acontece algum erro interno que não é apresentado no console.
Se eu instanciar a classe via php, funciona perfeitamente, só pelo jquery que não retorna nada. Estou usando o spl_autoload na só index.

**Controllers/FunilController.php**

```
<?php

namespace Controllers;
use Models\Vendas;

class FunilController
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $v = new Vendas;
    $vendas = $v->index();
    return $vendas
  }
}
```

**Models/Vendas.php**

```
<?php

namespace Models;
use Models\Conexao;

class Vendas extends Conexao
{
  public function index()
  {
    return 'olá';
  }
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function( $class ) {require_once str_replace( '\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class ) . '.php';});
?>

(...)

<script>
$.post('Models/Vendas.php',
 {solicitar: true, tab:1, cpf: Cpf, data_ini: dataIni, data_fim: dataFim},
 function(data){
 $('#res1').empty().append(data);
}, 'json');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente o erro está em contentType, tenta setar conforme o exemplo

```js
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/url",
   dataType : "json", // <--tipo de retorno esperado
   contentType: "application/json", // <-- tipo de dado enviado
   data: {
     solicitar: true, 
     tab:1, 
     cpf: Cpf,  
     data_ini: dataIni, 
     data_fim: dataFim},
   contentType: "application/json"
   success()
})
```

dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)) font: [Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Reestruture o retorno do seu Backend para um object json {msg:"Olá"}

Comment: Não sei porque, mas não está enviando os dados via post:

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "Controllers/JsonController.php",
data: {
solicitar: true, 
tab:4, 
cpf: Cpf,
data_ini: dataIni, 
data_fim: dataFim
},
contentType: "application/json",
beforeSend : function(){
console.log('enviando...'+Cpf);
}
})
.done(function(msg){
console.log(msg);
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, msg){
console.log(msg);
});

Comment: Ele não esta chegando no backend? Ou voce não está tendo um retorno??

Comment: Está chegando, por que eu consegui retornar o olá, só não está recendo o dados passados por post lá.

Comment: Ah sim, dataType (string), atualizei o código, veja se da certo... O backend está retornando um "olá"??

Comment: Continua sem receber o post, está retornando o 'fora':

if(isset($_POST['solicitar']) or isset($_POST['cpf']))
{
    echo json_encode('aqui');
}
else {
    echo json_encode('fora');
}

Comment: To começando a achar que o problema não está no post.

Comment: Você costuma usar namespace em seus projetos? Por que é a primeira vez que estou usando e está dando isso =/

Comment: @GlenysMitchell faz assim tente o post, pelo postman, ai veremos onde está o erro...